# can a 240 dryer outlet be moved using a junction box?

Tags: wiring

A dryer was moved and the people put a junction box in its place.  Can I run the new line by attaching to the old one using the junction box.  They just disconnected it and turned off the breaker.  I would like to reuse the line for another item requiring 240 power in my garage. Can this be done and still follow code?

Comment: Key questions: What **size** wire from breaker to junction box? How **many** wires? Are the wires in **conduit** or are they a cable?

Comment: Additionally, ask all those questions about the run from the junction box to the new location... BTW - Welcome to [diy.se]! Please [edit] your post to include the answers if you know them. If you're not sure, edit in pictures (click the "mountain" icon above the question [edit] box and upload them from your PC, SE will host them for you and embed them in the post for easier viewing), that show the breaker in question and the wiring inside the box. Get a clear, focused close up shot of the writing on the wiring in the box if at all possible.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the existing junction box please?  Also, what is this item that requires 240V power?

Comment: I think the wording of your question is confusing, and you might get incomplete answers as a result.  Where you write, *I would like to reuse the line for another item*, that is problematic.  You can only have one receptacle on a 30A 240V circuit.  It sounds to me like you should pull a new home-run circuit to the new dryer location and install a new breaker for it, or not re-purpose the old receptacle/circuit.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes if the conductors meet code.you already turned off,  Remove The receptacle install a clamp in the old box for the new wire to feed the new the receptacle If Romex the putter insulation 1/4” inside the clamp and 6” wire minimum. Use appropriate sized wire-nuts and install a blank cover, put the new box where you want it , bring the wire in make sure to have at least 6” and the putter covering or insulation inside the box by 1/4” reconnect your receptacle and you are ready to plug in. 
Electric driers are usually #10 wire on a 30 amp breaker. Can be larger but that is normal.
I usually use 4 square metal boxes with a 30 amp 1/2” raised cover .  The receptacle should be a 4 wire by today’s code well and the last few cycles.
Good luck.